# CacheDependency and the VirtualPathProvider for paths wirh dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are using the BundleTransformer library in an ASP.NET MVC 4 setup. Our web application is a rather thin layer, with all server logic handled in a backend service.

After an installation all resource will be installed along side the web application on the file system, but for update reasons we need to be able to serve resources like JavaScript and CSS (LESS) from the service - they will then override the local (file system) versions.

In essence, if available from the service, we serve a requested resource from there. If not, we fall-back to the file system and serve the file from there.

It was all working like a charm, then we introduced LESS and `@import` statements, now things are not working so fine anymore.

We still want to cache the result of the LESS transformation in the Http Cache, and we would like to invalidate that result whenever a dependency changes. The current implementation in the VirtualPathProvider does that, but if I update a single file (a JavaScript file for instance), it will not be updated.

My VirtualPathProvider looks like this:

```
public class ViewsAndScriptsPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider {

    private static IApplicationServiceResourcesManager ResourceManager {
        get { return InstanceProvider.Get<IApplicationServiceResourcesManager>(); }
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) {
        var exists = ResourceManager.Exists(virtualPath);
        return exists || base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
        VirtualFile file;
        if (ResourceManager.TryGet(virtualPath, out file)) {
            return file;
        }
        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) {
        bool isRelevant = ResourceManager.IsRelevant(virtualPath);
        if (isRelevant) {
            var cachekeys = virtualPathDependencies.Cast<string>().Where(dependency => virtualPath != dependency).ToArray();
            return new CacheDependency(null, cachekeys);
        }
        if (IsBundle(virtualPath)) {
            return new CacheDependency(null, new[] { ResourceManager.ComponentCacheKey }, utcStart);
        }
        return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }

    private bool IsBundle(string virtualPath) {
        return virtualPath.StartsWith("~/bundles/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
               || virtualPath.StartsWith("~/css/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies) {
        byte[] bhash;
        string filehash;
        if (ResourceManager.TryGetFileHash(virtualPath, out bhash)) {
            filehash = BitConverter.ToString(bhash);
        } else {
            filehash = Previous.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
        }
        return filehash;
    }
}
```

Think of the ResourceManager as a proxy / cache towards the service.

My big issue is that I don't understand exactly the CacheDependency work. If I add a cachekey (the second parameter) that includes the virtualPath itself, then I get an infinite loop in the server.
If I simply return `null` it won't work for LESS `@imports`.

If anybody could explain or point to how the VirtualPathProvider is supposed to implement the GetCacheDependency and the GetFileHash functions, I might be able to solve this one.

Comment: Great question. Too bad that no resposes yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually worked out a solution some time ago, and it has to do with how the HttpCache works with the CacheDependency object. It is rather complex however.

Basically I have three scenarios:

1. The resource is hosted only on the file system.
2. The resource is hosted only at the service.
3. The resource is hosted at both the service and the local file system.

For 1. I use the CacheDependency object for the file location. This is standard and how the VirtualPathProvider works by default.

For 2. I use a custom (derived) ResourceCacheDependency which implement logic to invalidate itself when the proxy has a new version.

For 3. I use the AggregateCacheDependency object that has both a CacheDependency to the physical file and a ResourceCacheDependency object.

For all virtual path dependencies (the list of dependencies for the resource) I repeat the above assumptions, and build it into the AggreateCacheDependency (it will potentially have a lot of dependencies).

In my custom implementation of the VirtualPathProvider I override the GetCacheDependency method to return the relevant CacheDependency object based on the above analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still can you please explain `how the GetCacheDependency, GetFileHash, GetCacheKey functions work?` What is the criteria of generating the CacheKey, Filehash? What parameter should we pass to CacheDependency object. Can you please provide some sample. Lets assume that we're serving some some files from custom folder on filesystem. Any help is appreciated!!